# awk - print second column if 4 and 5 column had a matching words

Tags: awk, grep, text-formatting

I have a txt file with 5 columns, like this for example

```
F1 rsfldo4pw F5 ABC  POG
F2 rsfcl2eou F6 ABD  POF
F3 rsfceleou F7 ABG  POE
```

I want a result of a text file that print the word in column 2 if column 4 is `ABD`, and column 5 is `POF`, like the above example it should print
`rsfcl2eou`.

I used this code but it doesn't work, could you help and correct it please?

```
'{if ( ($4=="ABD" && $5=="POF") 
    || ($4=="ABG" && $5=="POE") 
    || ($4=="ABK" && $5=="POJ") 
    || ($4=="ABT" && $5=="POB"))  print $2, "eltext" ;
  else print $2;}' ${DataFile.txt} |
 grep -v eltex > ${tempo.txt}
```

Comment: 5 columns? Please show them - I see 4 - not 5.

Comment: yeah sry, actually this is an examples not actual data , 
let's say F1 rsfldo4pw F4 ABC POG
could you correct the awk command for listing column 2's word to a txt file whenever it match specified words in column 4 and 5 like ($4=="ABD" && $5=="POF")
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure of the correct functions of each them i copied this code and i'm still trying to understand the basics, 
I just want the awk to read from a txt file "DataFile.txt" , to read whenever columon 4 and 5 has a matching words , then print column 2's word from the same row.

you can give me an example code to test on it..my problem is that the end result is a text file with all column 2's words from all rows , which means something is wrong in my code.

Comment: Please edit your original question with appropriate actions/answers when others ask questions via comments, such as the difference between saying five columns but only four columns are shown. Providing incorrect details, or sample data, at best results in incorrect answers. It also confuses others who come here seeking similar solutions to similar problems. The site is for the general public, not just you.

Comment: Please keep it simple for us - don't talk about columns 5 & 6 then show us 4 columns and then add a comment saying you really meant columns 4 and 5, etc. Just [edit] your question to show an example and tells us your requirements in terms of the columns in that example, with all input, output, code, and text talking about the same columns. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

to filter line bases on column

```
awk '$4 == "ABC" && $5 == "DEF" '
```

to print only field 2

```
awk '$4 == "ABC" && $5 == "DEF" { print $2} '
```

with multiple conditions

```
awk '$4 == "ABC" && $5 == "DEF" { print $2} 
     $4 == "XYZ" && $5 == "GHI" { print $2} '
```

lines not matching condition will be ignored, there is no need for additionnal `grep -v`

---

redirection and variable

note that  `${datafile.txt}` will not expand to `datafile.txt`

use either

```
awk '... ' input.txt > output.txt
```

or

```
input="Datafile.txt"
output="Exportfile.txt"
awk '...' ${input} > ${output}
```

you might want to quote variable, in case there is a special char

```
awk '...' "${input}" > "${output}"
```

Comment: can you modify the code to read from Datafile.txt and export the end result to exportfile.txt ?
also can you tell why there's no separator between each condition ? 
like $4 == "ABC" && $5 == "DEF" { print $2}  , shouldn't it get separated from another row where another condition $4 == "XYZ" && $5 == "GHI" { print $2} ? 
I'm trying to understand the basics.

Comment: Thank you very much its working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '(($4 " " $5 == "ABD POF") ||
      ($4 " " $5 == "ABG POE") ||
      ($4 " " $5 == "ABK POJ") ||
      ($4 " " $5 == "ABT POB")) { print $2 }' DataFile.txt > exportfile.txt
```

This simplifies it a little, by comparing the concatenation of $4 and $5 with the concatenations of the two 3-letter strings you want to match them against.

It also eliminates 3 of the 4 repeated code blocks in Archemar's answer (i.e. `{print $2}`).  See [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for a quick summary of why it's generally good practice to avoid multiple copies of the same code in the same program.

---

If you were absolutely certain that there weren't any combinations of $4 and $5 like ABD and either POE or POJ or POB etc in the input that you **don't** want to match, you could use a single regular expression match instead of four fixed-string matches:

```
awk '$4 " " $5 ~ /^AB[DGKT] PO[FEJB]$/ {print $2}' DataFile.txt  > exportfile.txt
```

This will match **all** combinations of AB followed by either D,G,K, or T and PO followed by either F,E,J, or B, not just the 4 combinations you listed.